# Connect an ethernet printer to a router wirelessly?

Tags: router, laptop, network-printer, brother-printer

I'm trying to connect my printer (brother mfc-7360n) which has USB and ethernet ports to a Linksys WRT54GL router wirelessly rather than through ethernet cable, is there a solution to make this possible, I have another router which maybe would be utilized for this purpose?

Comment: Can you put open firmware, e.g. OpenWRT, on the router? And have a look at [wlan_kabel](https://github.com/escitalopram/wlan_kabel)

Answer (score 1):

If that second Wifi router is able to work as a Wifi station (client) instead of an AP (unlikely, since it's not a common feature of home grade routers) then it might be a solution but it's bit of an overkill.

But you should check out a [Wireless Print Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Print_server) device which connects to the printer via USB and the to the network via Wifi. [TP Link, D-Link and similar manufacturers](https://www.ebay.com/bhp/wireless-print-server) have such things in their product portfolio. Compatibility might be an issue tho. I had bad experiences with TP Link print servers using with old HP LaserJets.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an Ethernet to WiFi bridge device, for example the [IOGEAR GWU627](https://www.iogear.com/product/GWU627)*. This would connect physically to your printer’s Ethernet port and wirelessly to your router.

- Note: this is just one example of suitable products. This is not an endorsement of this particular device or brand.